# CiviCase Users Unable to Edit & Add Activities on Cases They've Been Assigned

Tags: civicase, activities, permissions, error

We have assigned the Wordpress Access Control permission “CiviCase: access my cases and activities” to a variety of users who we want to assign case roles to.  The description of “CiviCase: access my cases and activities” permission indicates that users with this permission should be able to view and edit case activities with cases they are associated with.

Users with this permission can view the cases that they've been assigned to, but they are unable to edit case activities and add case activities on cases that they’ve been assigned a role to. A popup box that says "Sorry, an error occured. You are not authorized to view this page" appears. The only way users assigned to a case are able to edit and add new activities to a case they've been assigned to is to enable the permission "CiviCase: access all cases and activities", which is something we prefer to not enable.

Another Civicrm user brought this issue a couple of weeks ago, so it appears to be an issue experienced by other users. It's a significant issue for organizations that will rely on Civicase. **Is there a bug?**

[Users with Case roles cannot edit activities assigned to them: is this a bug?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9694/users-with-case-roles-cannot-edit-activities-assigned-to-them-is-this-a-bug)

We are using Civicrm Wordpress version 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

To me this reads like a bug - either the description is misleading, or the permission isn't functioning. You should log this at issues.civicrm.org, including all the detail you've added here (and a link back to this page).

Your options from there are basically:
1) Wait for the core team to fix it.
2) Pay for the core team to fix it.
3) Recruit a freelancer or an agency to fix it for you.

Message me if you want me to look at this in more depth for you.